# My graphics card doesn't work properly. What software can I use to connect to my laptop to my non working desktop?

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, remote-access

I want full control without lag, without display problems... Essentially I want to use my laptop's screen and graphics card as my desktop's screen and graphics card.  I have a very fast router/home network.

How do I accomplish this?

Note: The desktop runs Windows 7 Ultimate, the laptop runs Windows Vista Home Premium.

Comment: What sorts of activities are you planning on doing over this RDP/VNC connection? movies? games? standard office work?

Comment: I hope I could do all the above and more.

Comment: The problem with that is the GPU on the host computer will still be running the requests and handling the video or game, you will just be viewing it with RDP or VNC. You can always run them off of the host computer by just executing them over a network share, that will run everything on your laptop. I suppose I fail to see exactly why you want the desktop in the scenario at all.

Comment: because all my programs are on the desktop.  How can I use a network share???  Also I can no longer access my desktop (screen won't work, so I'd have no Idea what I'm clicking...).  Is there any way I can install programs without the cooperation of the desktop computer? Ex. just add lots of registry keys, and put a file in the program files (via shared c:\)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use built-in Remote Desktop Connection or [TightVNC](http://www.tightvnc.com/). However, there will be display lag, no matter how fast your network and system is.

Comment: Although I don't believe that Windows Vista Home Premium has remote desktop capabilities built in. So TightVNC (or another VNC software package) may be the only bet.

Comment: If lag is that much of a concern, try Radmin - it's by far the fastest screen rendering over a LAN.

Comment: @wizlog You may find [PsExec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553) useful for enabling remote desktop or for setting up TightVNC on your desktop - it can execute processes on a remote machine

Comment: Why will there always be a lag?

Comment: @wizlog by lag I don't mean constant stuttering or large amount of frame-drops, rather small noticeable delay for rapidly changing screen elements e.g. browser smooth-scroll.

Comment: Also I can no longer access my desktop (screen won't work, so I'd have no Idea what I'm clicking...). Is there any way I can install programs without the cooperation of the desktop computer? Ex. just add lots of registry keys, and put a file in the program files (via shared c:)?